# Drupal Search with two fields?

Tags: drupal, search, drupal-6

How can I add a second field to Drupal Search? F.e. Search all TITLE in CITY (two text fields)

I did a new input to the template and I want to call module_db_rewrite_sql() and left join the query but i can't get to POST data from my new field.

Any ideas?
dump

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adding the second field to the template, I would suggest using [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!hooks!core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) to alter Drupal's core search form.  Lullabot also has a nice [tutorial](https://www.lullabot.com/articles/modifying-forms-drupal-5-and-6) on the subject.

Comment: And how can I get to this data in module_db_rewrite_sql()?